# How to factor numbers that are the product of two primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

What are techniques to factor numbers that are the product of two prime numbers? For example, how would we factor $262417$ to get $397\cdot 661$? Would we have to guess that factorization or is there an easier way?

Comment: "Guessing" a factorization is about it.  Of course, you could just start with "2" and try dividing by factors up to the square root of the number.  But there is no 'easy' way to find prime factors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Comment: The reverse of Fermat's little theorem: if p divides the number N then $2^{p-1}$ equals 1 mod p, but computing mod p is consistent with computing mod N, therefore subtracting 1 from a high power of 2 Mod N will eventually lead to a nontrivial GCD with N. This works best if p-1 has many small factors.

Comment: There has been an awful lot of work done on the problem, and there are algorithms that are much better than the crude try everything up to $\sqrt{n}$. But as far as is publicly known at least, there is no known "fast" algorithm. For numbers of the size you mention, and even much larger, there are many programs that will give a virtually instantaneous answer.

Comment: If guessing the factorization is necessary, the number will be so large that a guess is virtually impossibly right. Numbers upto $80$ digits are routine with powerful tools, $120$ digits is still feasible in several days. From $200$ on, it will become difficult unless you use many computers. I do not know, where the practical limit of feasibility is, but from some magnitude on, it becomes infeasible to factor the number in general.

Comment: @Peter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge would give an idea of where the edge of feasibility lies with current technology and techniques.

Answer (score 5):

The problem of the factorization is the main property of some cryptograpic systems as RSA.

This fact has been studied for years and nowadays we don't know an algorithm to factorize a big arbitrary number efficiently.

However, if $p*q$ satisfies some propierties (e.g $p-1$ or $q-1$ have a soft factorization (that means the number factorizes in primes $p$ such that $p \leq \sqrt{n}$)), you can factorize the number in a computational time of $O(log(n))$ (or another low comptutational time)

If you are interested in it, you can check this pdf with some famous attacks to the security of RSA related with the fact of factorization of large numbers.

[http://www.nku.edu/~christensen/Mathematical%20attack%20on%20RSA.pdf](http://www.nku.edu/%7Echristensen/Mathematical%20attack%20on%20RSA.pdf)

Comment: "and nowadays we don't know a algorithm to factorize a big arbitrary number." — of course we know such an algorithm. What we don't know is an algorithm that does it *efficiently.* Which means that *in practice* we cannot factorize them. But only because we don't have the necessary resources to do so (primality testing is very well parallelizable, so if you were to turn the moon completely into microprocessors and found a way to adequately provide them with energy and cooling, you'd have no problem cracking any current RSA key.

Comment: Err … in my previous comment replace "primality testing" by "factorization", of course (although the algorithm is basically the same, try to divide by every possible factor).

Comment: Of note from your linked document is that Fermat’s factorization algorithm works well if the two factors are roughly the same size, namely we can then use the difference of two squares $n=x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ to find the factors. Of course we cannot know this a priori.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being a necromancer ...

... factorising a number we know to be the product of two primes should be easier than factorising a number where we don't know that.

Has anyone done an attack based on working backwards through the number?

For example, as we know 262417 is the product of two primes, then these primes must end with 1,7 or 3,9.  Our solution is therefore abcde1 x fghij7 or klmno3 x pqrst9 where the letters need to be determined.

Now work with the last pair of digits in each potential solution (e1 x j7 and o3 x t9) and eliminate all those digits for e, j, o and t which do not produce a 1 as the fifth digit.  We have the complication of dealing with possible carries.

Obviously the tree will expand rather quickly until it begins to contract again when investigating the frontmost digits.

Comment: In practice I highly doubt this would yield any greater efficiency than more routine approaches.

Comment: If you use Pollard-rho for example, you expect to find the smallest prime factor of n in O(n^(1/4)). If you haven't found a factor after say 5 n^(1/4) rounds then you start suspecting that n is prime and do a probabilistic primalty check.